# Why doesn't $ find . return a result for the .. directory shortcut?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, find

I'm wondering why a simple `$ find .` doesn't return `..` as one of the search results. FWIW, doing `$ find .` does return `.` as a search result, and if a soft link to the parent directory exists in `./`, then that link will show up in the results as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To answer your question sensibly, you should post the complete `find` command. Aside from this, it would be a bad design if `find` would follow the `..` entry. If it did, every `find` command would effectly search the whole file system.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of it the logic with "find" is that it will descend in the directory listed. So if find returned the ".." then it would look further into ".." and it would find another ".." and you see where this would go. Find would start going up in the file system and every find would be a find starting from "/".
So i'd say this is by design, and it makes sense it is this way.

Comment: Thanks. One exception to the "descend in the directory listed" behavior is the treatment of the . directory. The command makes an exception for . (in that it doesn't infinitely regress into itself).